# C++ client sends weird data to Java server

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I made a java server and a c++ client (TCP connection)
On the server i made an easy login that checks if two variables are the same.
When c++ client sends the data to the server it recieves some weird data with many spaces and custom characters like    ĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚ   ĚĚĚĚĚĚĚĚ.

The c++ client sends data like this:
(ignore some variables like server_socket becouse i didn't add it to the code to tweak it a bit)

```
char buffer[1024];

        cin >> buffer;
        string message = buffer;
        message.append("\n");

        if (send(server_socket, message.c_str(), sizeof(buffer), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cout << "Error CS#001" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
```

The java server recieves like this:

```
            clientMessage = s.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(clientMessage));
            reader.ready();
            String message = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: `sizeof(buffer) == 1024`, irrespective of the length of the actual text. So you are sending the characters in `message`, plus whatever random garbage happens to follow them in memory, for 1024 bytes total.

Comment: Oh yeah! Forgot about that! Fixed it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Consider ditching `buffer` and reading the user input directly into `message`.

Comment: Yeah, did exactly that.